# Change tooltip text on click (toggle)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have an input checkbox stylized like a switch, and a tooltip near it. I want to if the user click in the checkbox, it shows a text in the tooltip, and if click again (unchecked) it shows another text. I tried it but when is checked the tooltip dissapear.

The main structure:

```
<div class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></label>
</div> 
<div class="tooltip fade bottom in" style="display: block;top: 52px;width: 115px;left: 16.5px;">
    <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
    <div id="tp1" class="tooltip-inner">Activar todas</div>
</div>
```

The JQuery Code (i don't know why if i put this in document ready() doesn't work, if i place out it's only work when the checkbox is checked:

```
 $(".switch").click(function() {
        $(".tooltip").toggle();
        if ($("#tp1").text() == "Activar todas") {
            $("#tp1").text("Remove comment");
        }
        else {
            $("#tp1").text("Activar todas");
        }
    });
```

The JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6hJ3J/

Comment: Your code works. The issue is that `toggle` makes the parent of the `div` whose text you're changing invisible. Comment that and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/jSWg2/1/

Answer (score -1):

Load Jquery lib in Fiddle then put your code in document ready

Try this

```
 $(document).ready(function()
   $(".switch").click(function () {
    if ($("#tp1").text() == "Activar todas") {
     $("#tp1").text("Remove comment");
    } else {
     $("#tp1").text("Activar todas");
    }
   });
 });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6hJ3J/6/)

Comment: Why would you want to re-toggle in every case? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks! And why it's doesn't work in the document ready function?

Comment: What he posted works but it is not ok. You get the same effect if ou just remove all `$(".tooltip").toggle();`

Comment: @Downvoters OP want toggle effect after change thats why i added

Comment: I downvote for an answer that is a bad solution even if it might "work".

Comment: @Esa but OP need effect thats why code have that part